# Make image full width - Wordpress HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So my container is 1230px, the image is 1250px but when I add it in it's still showing up as 1210px.

http://insightcxo.com/test-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's padding being applied to the td tag. Add a `padding: 0;` rule to your css for that td and it will fill the width.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to parent  padding: 10px 0;

Answer (score 0):

It's because your container (td) has 10 px of padding on the right and left.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
classname {
    padding: 0x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container, 
.navbar-static-top .container, 
.navbar-fixed-top .container, 
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
  width: 1170px;
}
```

To:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container, 
.navbar-static-top .container, 
.navbar-fixed-top .container, 
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
  width: auto;
}
```